# placing a Tabbar controller on top of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

[image: how to connect them.]How do i place the TABBAR control on top of view control.by default it is at bottom how do i put it up..?

Used following code to do:

```
 UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"footer-bg.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance]setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer-hover-bg.png"]];

if(IS_IOS_7)
{
    [[appDelegate.tabBarController tabBar] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer-hover-bg.png"]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50);
appDelegate.tabBarController.delegate=self;

UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 600)];

viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

MainViewController *view1 = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view1];
[viewControllers addObject:nav1];

ViewController1 *view2 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view2];
[viewControllers addObject:nav2];

[appDelegate.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBarController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[view addSubview:appDelegate.tabBarController.view];

[self.view addSubview:view];

UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];


[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arraySelectedImages objectAtIndex:0]] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayUnselectedImages objectAtIndex:0]]];
[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arraySelectedImages objectAtIndex:1]] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayUnselectedImages objectAtIndex:1]]];
```

How do i do the same using storyboards?

Answer (score 3):

First add a `UIViewController` then add the `UITabBar` and add contraint if you use autolayout.

[image]

Don't forgot to connect delegate.

Hope that will help.

Comment: i have used UITabBarController and added views to it.can i change its frame so that i can add it above.

Comment: No. If you use UITabBarController you will be not able to change the position

Comment: can u please give me sample links for Tabbar using storyboards.I couldn't find :(

Comment: a beginning : http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/ios-dev-add-tabbar-to-a-view-without-a-tabbarcontroller/

Comment: Thanks a lot :).How do i connect first view controller with the first tabbaritem in a stroyboard?.I am not able load view controller.

Comment: the first view will be the current view ^^

Comment: this code doesnt work - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    switch (item.tag) {
        case 1:
            if (tab1vc == nil)
            {
                UIStoryboard *storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:Nil];
                mainTabbar = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
               // self.tab1vc =[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
            }
            [self.view insertSubview:tab1vc.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
            break;

Comment: it is not related to my question :( there is no tabbar init.

Comment: don't build your app as `UITabBarController` because you DON'T have a UITabBarController. just navigate in the app without an `NavigationController` or `UITabBarController` like in this answer...